# Getting error when running python file using doppler. "Doppler Error: fork/exec....."

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, containers, doppler

I'm trying to run a file using Doppler. This command worked a few weeks ago but when I restarted my virtual environment, I started getting this error and cannot figure it out. The file runs fine without doppler.

I run the command:

```
doppler run -c dev -- my_file.py
```

Error I get      :

```
Doppler Error: fork/exec my_file.py: %1 is not a valid_Win32application
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solved: All I need to do was

`doppler run -c dev -- python my_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to set the env vars:

```
export DOPPLER_PROJECT=your-project
export DOPPLER_CONFIG=dev
```